# emotion-js on Create React App - 'jsx' is defined but never used

Tags: reactjs, eslint, emotion, typescript-eslint

So I tried to use `emotion-js` for the first time and get hooked by the css prop feature.

While trying what the documentation says I get a warning from the eslint.

> 'jsx' is defined but never used  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars

The script that I use looks like this.

```
import React from "react";
//** @jsx jsx */
import { jsx } from "@emotion/core";

export const Component = () => {
    return (
        <div css={{color: red}}>
            This is a component
        </div>
    )
}
```

I'm using VSCode, so I can see that this import is tagged as never used. (Has transparent color)

[image: The jsx import is transparent (Never used)]

But I did use it for my div, and if I remove the import, my css prop is showing an error.

Please help as to how to avoid this eslint warning, or at least make the VSCode recognize that jsx is being used.

Thanks!

---

Edit: (Adding reference)

Reference: https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop#jsx-pragma

---

Edit 2: I tried adding `.eslintrc` file that looked like this

```
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
  "extends": ["plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"],
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": [
      2,
      { "vars": "all", "args": "all", "varsIgnorePattern": "^jsx$" }
    ]
  }
}
```

Still get the warning, did I do it wrong?

Comment: `jsx` *is* being used, probably by https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx

Comment: But why is my typescript-eslint sends this warning? It doesn't seem like it recognize that jsx is being used. This jsx warnings will be disturbing when my project is becoming bigger. :s

Comment: This can be easily fixed by adding `// eslint-disable-next-line`, but does anyone has a better solution? Maybe to get this jsx import to be recignized as being used by the css prop?

Comment: Because the linter doesn't know that! Have you tried configuring the rule globally to ignore that name?

Comment: I will try doing that, I have never tried to change the rule tho.

Comment: How do I change the eslint rule? Tried doing it but failed :(

Comment: it might be the spelling on the comment, i've only gotten it to work with `/* @jsx jsx */` or `/** @jsx jsx */` with a single leading slash

Answer (score 1):

Emotion provides [its own eslint plugin](https://emotion.sh/docs/@emotion/eslint-plugin) that should handle this automatically for you.

Another approach is to use [emotion's babel plugin](https://emotion.sh/docs/@emotion/babel-plugin) to automatically add the `jsx` import and `jsx` pragma comment automatically at compile time. This way, you no longer need to add them in each of your file.

Comment: I tried adding the plugin and using the babel plugin and it didn't stop the `'jsx' is defined but never used` warning from happening.  Any other ideas or thoughts on what I might have overlooked?

Comment: Those kinds of warnings probably come from ESLint. Have you tried configuring ESLint to use emotion's provided ESLint plugin? Though if you are using the babel plugi already, you should be able to just remove the jsx import.

Answer (score 1):

- Install [Emotion's ESlint plugin](https://emotion.sh/docs/@emotion/eslint-plugin)
- Add `"@emotion"` to the array of plugins in your .eslintrc file
- Remove the jsx import from your src files
- Double-check you have the correct linter config comment at the top of your file `/** @jsx jsx */` vs `/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */` [emotion css prop docs](https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop#jsx-pragma)
- Restart your app server

Answer (score 0):

I found this trick to fix the warning.

**1. Add eslint and typescript-eslint dependencies**

```
yarn add --dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin @typescript-eslint/parser eslint
// or if you use npm
npm install --save-dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin @typescript-eslint/parser eslint
```

**2. Create `.eslintrc` file** (change the config as needed)

```
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": [
      2,
      {
        "vars": "all",
        "args": "all",
        "varsIgnorePattern": "^jsx$",
        "argsIgnorePattern": "[Ii]gnored$"
      }
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off"
  }
}
```

**3. Install Eslint Extension on VSCode**
This is useful to automatically run the eslint in your code editor ([here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint)).

**4. Extend CRA's Eslint to Local Eslint** (ref: [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env))
Create `.env` file and add this line:

```
EXTEND_ESLINT=true
```

Now when you try to run yarn start or npm run start CRA will use your local ESLint to compile your script.

---

For more detailed information, feel free to read it on my Medium ([here](https://michael-harley.medium.com/using-create-react-app-typescript-with-custom-eslint-rules-5fc5aec3ff10)).