# how remove Unused import { jsx, css } from '@emotion/core'?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, emotion, eslintrc

my code contains :

`/** @jsx jsx */`

`import { jsx, css } from '@emotion/core';`

but eslint has error : `Unused import { jsx, css } from '@emotion/core'`.
how can I remove this error from my files? and I add this rule to my `eslintrc.js` file but it doesn't help:

```
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': 'off',
  }
```

thank you for your help!

Comment: can you tried setup new project with your change only and see what happen? with current information it does not enough to do debug

Comment: @lehanh Sorry, No, I can't. Do you need information about eslintrc or package.json?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [emotion-js on Create React App - 'jsx' is defined but never used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60355453/emotion-js-on-create-react-app-jsx-is-defined-but-never-used)

Comment: @vioarn I saw the post before and tried the answers but nothing changed.